# Colorbox showing up beneath iFrame containing flash video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page that contains the colorbox plugin and it also has an iframe that contains a youtube embedded video.

In FF my colorbox appears above the flash video only in chrome my iframes appear above the colorbox if this makes sense?

I've tried adding wmode=transparency to my flash videos and giving my colorbox a much higher z-index which both havent helped, is it possible to lay objects over an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct value is `wmode=transparent`.  Be sure you are adding both as param name :

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
```

and in the embed:

```
 wmode="transparent"
```